# Websocket accessing data from private-channel in flutter

Tags: flutter, websocket

I want to access data from a private-channel with authorization in web-socket. What will be the best solution for this. I’m searching about it but can’t find any solution.
Like-

```
Echo echo = new Echo({
  'broadcaster': 'socket.io',
  'host': 'http://test.api.tripegate.com:6001/',
  'client': IO.io,
  'auth': {
    'headers': {'Authorization': 'Bearer $referenceToken}
  }
});
echo.private(channelName).listen('.flight-search-result', (e) {
  print(e);
});
```